# A function in a nodejs module is defined, but shows undefined when acessed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am making a Discord bot in using NodeJS and TypeScript and am trying to import some custom modules in a loop using the following code:

```js
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync("./src/events/").filter((file: string) => file.endsWith('.ts'));

for(const file of eventFiles)
{
    const module: string = file.substring(0, file.length - 3);

    const event = require(`./events/${module}`);

    console.log(event);
    console.log(`Function: ` + event.exectue);

    if(event.once)
    {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.exectue(client, ...args));
    }
    else
    {
        if(event.isasync) client.on(event.name, async (...args) => await event.exectue(client, ...args));
        else client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.exectue(client, ...args));
    }
}
```

From the debugging I have done so far, it appears that I am successfully loading the execute functions from my modules when I log the module to the console, however the execute function is undefined on every module except the last one when I use the `execute` method?

Does anyone know what is happening? Thanks!

Edit: Here is a screenshot of my console to help you out [image]

Comment: You have a typo: `event.exectue` instead of `event.execute`, at your `console.log` and also later in your code where you try to use it.

Comment: And for the last module, you have the typo in your module where you actually exported that function as `exectue` instead of `execute`, that's why the last module works.

Comment: `I'm so stupid lol` typos are problems that happen to everyone.

Comment: With TS you should, however, be able to reduce the problem with typos by using `abstract` and `interface`, and enforcing types.

Comment: yeah, kinda new to typescript so I haven't learned that yet. Came from learning JavaScript, but I am a ton better at OOP like java/c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a typo in my code that I didn't know about for months.

I was calling `event.exectue` insteadof `event.execute`

**ALWAYS CHECK FOR TYPOS**